# RT5572STA interface doesn't support scanning

Tags: c, linux, wifi

I am using RT5572 USB Wifi adapter,after build able to load the driver but when we tried to scan the network using command line, got an error **"interface doesn't support scanning"** .
i have download source from http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/

```
and use following commands to build:
```

=======================================================================

## Build Instructions:

```
1> $tar -xvzf DPB_RT2870_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x.tgz
 go to "./DPB_RT2870_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x" directory.
2> In Makefile   
set the "MODE = STA" in Makefile and chose the TARGET to Linux by set "TARGET = LINUX"   define the linux kernel
 source include file path LINUX_SRC      modify to meet your need.

 3> In os/linux/config.mk   define the GCC and LD of the target machine
define the compiler flags CFLAGS    modify to meet your need.   ** Build
for being controlled by NetworkManager or wpa_supplicant wext
functions Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y'and'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y'. 
=> #>cd wpa_supplicant-x.x
=> #>./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d
4> $make
  # compile driver source code
 # To fix "error: too few arguments to function ¡¥iwe_stream_add_event"
 => $patch -i os/linux/sta_ioctl.c.patch os/linux/sta_ioctl.c

5> $cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
6> load driver, go to "os/linux/" directory.
#[kernel 2.6]
#    $/sbin/insmod rt2870sta.ko
#    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 inet YOUR_IP up
```

i am not able to understand the meaning of

```
=> #>cd wpa_supplicant-x.x
=> #>./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d
```

in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

the interface needs to be 'up' first

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: yes i tried this also. but nothing changed.. ubuntu 10.04 and linux version 2.6.32-38 genric. i did not see anything on GUI also..

Comment: yes i tried this also. but nothing changed.. ubuntu 10.04 and linux version 2.6.32-38 genric. i did not see anything on GUI also..